# Can't overwrite cell values using openpyxl ['MergedCell' is read-only]

Tags: python, openpyxl

Firstly iterating over spreadsheets in a dir, then trying to iterate over cells in column D, overwriting their values from a list. D1 = list[0], D2 = list[1] and so on.

```
from openpyxl import Workbook

i = 0
for copy in os.listdir(dir):
    wscopy = openpyxl.load_workbook(os.path.join(dir, copy))
    for cell in wscopy.active['D']:
        cell.value = converted_numbers[i]
        i += 1
    wb.save(copy)
```

Issue seems to be that some cell attributes are 'cell' while others are 'mergedcell', the latter of which cannot be overwritten. Full error:

"AttributeError: 'MergedCell' object attribute 'value' is read-only"

Any suggestions?

Comment: Open the Excel file, see which cells are merged and check if it's feasible to unmerge them.

Answer (score 1):

Excel relies on MergedCells for formatting borders and this introduces dangerous ambiguity into worksheets because the cells could contain real values even though they're supposed to be merged.

To solve this in openpyxl we created MergedCells, which will preserve any border formats (no other formatting requires them) but which cannot be altered. The exception is intended to help the user from any unexpected side effects, which would be the case here.

You can easily work around this with a try and except clause:

```
try:
    cell.value = = converted_numbers[i]
except AttributeError:
    if isinstance(cell, MergedCell):
        warn(f"Failed trying to assign a value to MergedCell {cell.coodinates}")
```

Comment: That's brilliant! Thanks a lot Charlie!

I did initially write a try-except clause but checked for type(cell) == 'MergedCell'. The object type was something like cell.cell.MergedCell (tried copying and pasting that too into the above), but now I see I should have been checking for instance not type.

Thanks again!

Comment: The differences between types and class instances can be confusing. In general, it's probably best to use `type()` only for builtins.